# Xcode code stripping doesn't strip all symbols

Tags: xcode, build, strip

When I build my project in Xcode (for debug or archiving) and specify Strip Debug Symbols:

```
Strip Linked Product    YES
Strip Style             ALL SYMBOLS
Additional Strip Flags  -S -x
```

I still have items in my compiled application that shouldn't be there such as:

```
/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/John Smith/Xcode/Builds/Trial Application/Classes/Data+CommonConvert.m
```

How do I specify not to leave that information in build phase of my application?

Comment: What "items"? This doesn't look like a function name, rather a file path...

Comment: By the way, any chance you are using `assert()` or some other macro like that which prints the file path upon encountering an assertion failure? Because then a string literal is created and stored in the executable...

Comment: @H2CO3 - not using assert(), and no errors or failures. By 'items' you are correct - it's showing the file paths of my classes within my project after I build. I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: check setting 'deployment postprocessing'